# I'm trying to install ElasticSearch on a Linux environment. but return "failed: Network is unreachable."

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, deployment

I want to use elasticsearch. but my level is vey low TT..

I'm following a tutorial. 
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/zip-targz.html)

But i am having trouble from the start.
Firstly commend like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwVm5.png)
then i show like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkjGe.png)

I have deploy several service. But I don't know concept of deploying with elasticsearch. Port...Key ... etc. so i'm confused. Would you please reference?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To start with this question may be better suited to serverfault than SO. In any case it looks like the ES mirror hosting the content was not reachable from where you are (or down). Try another mirror.

Comment: If you want to set it up on aws, why not use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticsearch-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your connection. Maybe for some reason, you cannot connect to `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.1.4.tar.gz` ?
Try to open this [link](http://%20wget%20https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.1.4.tar.gz) on browser, like chrome?

Comment: Thank you! When i try to open link, browser say can't find IP.

Comment: It's because of your connection. If you're dev-ing on local, I suggest you might wanna use docker instead. There're a lot of repo on github has docker for elasticsearch. You can easily find it. And if you're interested in using docker, check out [my repo](https://github.com/HoangTien339/elk_stack).